# select function keep returning -1

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, tcplistener, winsock2

im trying to make a simple example that accept clients using tcp socket and handle them with select function of winsock.

The problem is that when ever i run the select function it keeps return me the value -1 (error) and WSAGetLastError return the value of 10022.

I cant find out what im doing wrong because the fd_set is setting with the sockets properly and the maximum_sd set to the right value.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>
#include <queue>
#include <string.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

void SlaveThread(queue<char*>* tasks);
void MasterThread(queue<char*>* tasks);

fd_set readfds;
int max_sd = 0;
deque<SOCKET> socketsQueue;
int nSocketsAmount = 0;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    queue<char*>* tasksQueue = new queue<char*>();
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    thread SecondThread(MasterThread,tasksQueue);
    thread FirstThread(SlaveThread,tasksQueue);

    int nReady;
    struct timeval timeout={0, 0};
    timeout.tv_sec=10;
    timeout.tv_usec=0;
    while (true)
    {
        int i;

        nReady = select(max_sd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

         for (i=0; i < nSocketsAmount && nReady > 0; i++)
         {
             SOCKET temp = socketsQueue[i];
             if (FD_ISSET(temp, &readfds)) {

                char buffer[200];
                memset(buffer, 0, 200);
                recv(temp, buffer, 200, 0);
                tasksQueue->push(buffer);
                nReady--;
            }
         }
    }

    FirstThread.join();
    SecondThread.join();
    return 0;
};

void SlaveThread(queue<char*>* tasks)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (!tasks->empty())
        {
            cout << tasks->front() << " Queue size : " << tasks->size() << endl;
            tasks->pop();
        }

        Sleep(1000);
    }
};

void MasterThread(queue<char*>* tasks)
{
    WSAData WinSockData;
    WORD Version = MAKEWORD(2, 1);

    WSAStartup(Version, &WinSockData);

    /* Create socket structure */
    SOCKADDR_IN Server;
    Server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.0.7");
    Server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    Server.sin_port = htons(27015);

    SOCKET ListenSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    SOCKET Connect;
    ::bind(ListenSock, (SOCKADDR*)&Server, sizeof(Server));
    int errno0 = WSAGetLastError();
    listen(ListenSock, 1);
    int errno1 = WSAGetLastError();
    cout << "Listening on port 27015" << endl;
    char buffer[200];
    int size = sizeof(Server);

    while (true)
    {
        if (Connect = accept(ListenSock, (SOCKADDR*)&Server, &size))
        {
            cout << "Connection established..." << endl;
            FD_SET(Connect, &readfds);

            socketsQueue.push_front(Connect);
            nSocketsAmount++;

            if (Connect > max_sd)
            {
                max_sd = Connect;
            }
        }
    }

    WSACleanup();
};
```

master thread adding the sockets to the fd_set and sockets queue. and the main use select to get the socket need to read from.

Any suggestions why is that happen?

Thank you.

Comment: Try moving the WSAStartup stuff to main, before calling `select`.

Comment: Have you considered looking up what WSA error 10022 means?

Comment: Yes i did, it's say invalid argument but i don't what wrong with the arguments i sent to select

Comment: You should have included that information in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Who (what documentation page) gave you permission to change `readfds` while `select` is using it?

When you pass a data structure to an API function, that function owns it until it returns (or longer, in the case of buffers for overlapped I/O).  You can't go overwriting it from another thread.

You need to combine your main `select` loop and your "master" thread, luckily `select` is perfectly capable of waiting for incoming connections on a listening socket.

The actual error you are getting is from violating this requirement found in the documentation:

> Any two of the parameters, readfds, writefds, or exceptfds, can be given as null. At least one must be non-null, and any non-null descriptor set must contain at least one handle to a socket.

After applying the redesign I describe above, the set will always contain the listening socket, fixing this problem as well.

Comment: But accept is blocking and then the select won't happen until a new connection will establish if i combine them isn't?

Comment: @asalregev Why are you using a separate accept() thread at all if you're also selecting on the same socket in another thread? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @EJP so what are you saying if im using select, it's replace the need of accepting clients?

Comment: @asafregev No, it replaces the need for a separately blocking accept thread. Just add the listening socket to the readfds, and when it becomes readable do an accept(). As you *aren't* presently selecting on the listening socket, it isn't true to say that select() will return when a new connection happens, so you *are* concurrently modifying the readfds, which explains your problem.

Comment: Having the listening socket in `readfds` also will fix the error from having an empty fd set.

Answer (score 0):

10022 is `WSAEINVAL`.  You are passing an invalid argument to `select()`.  One thing you are not taking into account is that `select()` modifies the provided `fd_set` structs on exit, so you have to reset them every time you call `select()`.  You are also not taking into account that you are modifying the `fd_set` while `select()` may still be using it.  And you are not protecting your task queues from concurrent thread access, either.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <string.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

struct taskQueue
{
    queue<char*> items;
    mutex itemsLock;
};

void SlaveThread(taskQueue *tasks);
void MasterThread(taskQueue *tasks);

deque<SOCKET> socketsQueue;
mutex socketsQueueLock;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    WSAData WinSockData;
    WORD Version = MAKEWORD(2, 1);

    WSAStartup(Version, &WinSockData);

    taskQueue tasks;
    thread SecondThread(MasterThread, &tasks);
    thread FirstThread(SlaveThread, &tasks);

    char *buffer = NULL;

    while (true)
    {
        fd_set readfds;
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);

        struct timeval timeout = {0};
        timeout.tv_sec = 10;
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;

        int nReady = 0;

        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lock(socketsQueueLock);
            for (deque<SOCKET>::iterator iter = socketsQueue.begin(); iter != socketsQueue.end(); ++iter)
            {
                FD_SET(*iter, &readfds);
                ++nReady;
            }
        }

        if (nReady == 0)
        {
            Sleep(100);
            continue;
        }

        nReady = select(0, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
        if (nReady > 0)
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lock(socketsQueueLock);
            for (deque<SOCKET>::iterator iter = socketsQueue.begin(); iter != socketsQueue.end(); ++iter)
            {
                SOCKET temp = *iter;
                if (FD_ISSET(temp, &readfds))
                {
                    if (!buffer)
                        buffer = new char[201];
                    memset(buffer, 0, 200);

                    nReady = recv(temp, buffer, 200, 0);
                    if (nReady > 0)
                    {
                        buffer[nReady] = 0;
                        lock_guard<mutex> lock2(tasks.itemsLock);
                        tasks.items.push(buffer);
                        buffer = NULL;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    FirstThread.join();
    SecondThread.join();

    delete[] buffer;

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
};

void SlaveThread(taskQueue *tasks)
{
    while (true)
    {
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lock(tasks->itemsLock);

            if (!tasks->items.empty())
            {
                char *buffer = tasks->items.front();
                cout << buffer << " Queue size : " << tasks->items.size() << endl;
                tasks->items.pop();
                delete[] buffer;
            }
        }

        Sleep(1000);
    }
};

void MasterThread(taskQueue *tasks)
{
    /* Create socket structure */
    SOCKADDR_IN Server = {0};
    Server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.0.7");
    Server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    Server.sin_port = htons(27015);

    SOCKET ListenSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (ListenSock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << "Cannot create listening socket. Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        return;
    }

    if (::bind(ListenSock, (SOCKADDR*)&Server, sizeof(Server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Cannot bind listening socket. Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(ListenSock);
        return;
    }

    if (listen(ListenSock, 1) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Cannot listen on port 27015. Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(ListenSock);
        return;
    }

    cout << "Listening on port 27015" << endl;

    char buffer[200];
    int size;
    SOCKET Connect;

    while (true)
    {
        size = sizeof(Server);
        Connect = accept(ListenSock, (SOCKADDR*)&Server, &size);
        if (Connect != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            cout << "Connection established..." << endl;

            lock_guard<mutex> lock(socketsQueueLock);
            socketsQueue.push_front(Connect);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: This can still call select with an empty set.  Doc says "Any two of the parameters, readfds, writefds, or exceptfds, can be given as null. At least one must be non-null, and any non-null descriptor set must contain at least one handle to a socket."